# Condition for solution of linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

*The problem is:*

> Let $A$ be a singular $N \times N$ matrix with real entries and let $\mathbf{b}$ be a $N \times 1$ matrix (i.e. column vector). Let $A^\top $  and $\mathbf{b}^\top$  be their respective transposes. Consider the system of $N$ linear equations in $N$ unknowns written in the matrix form as:
>   $$                                                                                                          A^\top\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}.
> $$
>   Complete the following sentence: The above linear system has a solution, if and only if, $$\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{u} = 0,$$ for all column vectors $\mathbf{u}$ such that …

Please help me in filling up the above blank.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $A^Tx = b$ has a solution only if $b$ is in the space spanned by the columns of $A^T$ (which are the rows of $A$). So you could say that $b$ must be orthogonal (ie scalar product is $0$) to the orthogonal space of $\text{Col } A^T$
(So if $b$ is orthogonal to the orthogonal of $\text{Col }A^T$ it means that it must be in $\text{Col }A^T$, which is what we want)

Now, the orthogonal complement of $\text{Col }A^T$ is $\text{Ker } A$! So in the end you can say that for every $u \in \text{Ker } A$ it must hold that

$$b^Tu = 0$$

@A.Chattopadhyay. Is that your comment or are you reporting what your professor told you? Anyhow, you must have misunderstood what I wrote; yours is not a countexample. In fact, if $A^T = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &  1 \\ 0 & 1  & 1 \\  1& 1 &2\end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, we have that $\text{ Ker } A  = \left\{u \in \mathbb R^3: u = \begin{pmatrix} -t \\ -t \\ t\end{pmatrix} \text{ for } t \in \mathbb R\right\}$. Hence for every $u \in \text{Ker } A$ we have $$u^Tb = -t\cdot 1 -t\cdot(-1) + t\cdot 0 = 0$$ as expected

Comment: I don't understand why are you claiming that b is orthogonal.Consider the system of equations:
x+z=1;y+z=-1,x+y+2z=0.  Suppose the co-efficient matrix here is the transpose of A.Then above system has solutions (why?).Then the scalar product gives 2 # 0.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. Scalar product of $b$ with what gives $2$? Anyhow, see my edit

Comment: I have understood what you have stated.But there is another hesitation created in my mind just now which is 'in the entire process you don't use the condition that A is singular.'Is it of no importance?Please inform me to make me understood the fact clearly.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. Indeed, it is of no importance, the above works even if $A$ is not singular. But of course, if $A$ is not singular then $\text {Ker } A = \{0\}$ so the condition $b^Tu= 0 $ is automatically satisfied for every $b$; and in fact you can indeed find a solution for every $b$ in that case

Comment: If A is non-singular then by matrix inversion method we can find solution of $A^Tx=b$.In fact then all the column vectors of A being linearly independent forms a basis of $IR^n$.Since b is also in $IR^n$.Hence, b is always $Col$ $A^T$ which is required for having a solution.Isn't it?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. Exactly, that was my point. And as you can see the condition $b^Tu = 0$ still holds in this case, so what I wrote is correct if $A$ is singular and also if it's not